# videojs plugin installation didnt work

Tags: plugins, video.js, playlist

i tried since friday to install a playlist plugin to videojs but it dosent work for me. 
i want this plugin : https://github.com/Belelros/videojs-playLists i red the documentation but i cant figured out what the problem is.

here are my Code snippets

```
     <video class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
        controls preload="auto" width="530" height="298"
         data-setup='{"plugins":{"videojs-playlists"}   }  '>
       <source src="../../../../../fileadmin/Film01.mp4" type='video/mp4' />

     </video> 

    </div>



    <div class="vt-video-player-playlist">

      <ul>
        <li data-videoplaylist="0">Critical Chain - in 5 Minuten erklärt</li>
        <li data-videoplaylist="1">Critical Chain Multi Projektmanagement</li>
        <li>Results of Critical Chain at von Ardenne..</li>
        <li>Zuverlässige Projekte - Sichere Liquidität</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
```

and at the end of the site i load the js files

```
<script src="../../../Public/3rd/jquery-1.10.2/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../../Public/Js/common.js"></script>
  <script src="../../../Public/Js/menuslider.js"></script>

  <script src="../../../Public/3rd/video-js/video.js"></script>
  <script src="../../../Public/3rd/videojs-playLists-master/dist/videojs-playlists.js"></script>
  <script src="../../../Public/Js/videoplayer-settings.js"></script>
```

i hope you can help me. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is currently an issue with the playlist which is basically this one:

https://github.com/Belelros/videojs-playLists/issues/6

The thing is that I was using some minified var name for getting `videojs` instance. I need to fix that ASAP. However, as a workaround, you can edit in Line 22 of  videojs-playlist, and replace this:

```
player.pl.el = player.N;
```

By this:

```
player.pl.el = player.a;
```

Worked for me on another file... Not an optimal solution but should at least work.